# JS undefined import when defining global const(undefined error)

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, import, es6-modules

### Context:

*This is not important for core of the question, but still providing for clarity.*

We are using [ant-mobile](https://github.com/ant-design/ant-design-mobile-rn) in our [react-native-web](https://github.com/necolas/react-native-web) app, it uses [react-native-collapsible](https://oblador@github.com/oblador/react-native-collapsible) internally(v1.5.1). Everything was working fine during web, but it started giving errors on release,

### Error

Error looked something like this:

[image: This is a cannot convert undefined or null to object, at Accordian.js:7]

But it should be working as code seems like so:

[image: code]

[*Code can also be accessed here.*](https://github.com/oblador/react-native-collapsible/blob/1be890e20897cb473c73ef7325eacea87ea3e175/Accordion.js)

### My solution:

I ended up writing a patch to remove this const and use its definition code where this const was being used([only 1 place](https://github.com/oblador/react-native-collapsible/blob/1be890e20897cb473c73ef7325eacea87ea3e175/Accordion.js#L67)). And everything worked.

### Question

My question is,
Why this was working in development and not in production builds?
Why `VIEW_PROPS` global const doesn't show this issue?
And least importantly, is there any babel config type thing i can use to transpile this instead of patching?

[*Issue created on the original library is here.*](https://github.com/oblador/react-native-collapsible/issues/304)

**UPDATE:** Turns out we were just not quiet hitting the line which i have moved this constant initialization in our usage, but now we are hitting that line and it seems more like prop-types being removed issue(see the above issue i have linked for details).